# What execution stack / .NET AppDomain holds file handle?

Tags: .net, windows, file, debugging, windbg

I have .NET executable which hosts plugins in separated AppDomains.
Sometimes during application usage one of this plugins locks files and prevents its moving or deletion.

I need to find out who holds File handles?

Issue is intermittent and hard to reproduce. There is 5 plugins.
It is not solution to forbid plugins to access this files or kill handles (like Unlocker does).

I tried:

First, Sysinternals - but it shows only process who holds file with specified name.

Second, as stated in articles and docs about WinDbg I can use !process and !handle, but get next:

```
0:001> !process
No export process found 
0:001> !handle 314 ff 123 
Unknown type '123
```

I can use !handle with less parameters, but my version (for unknown reason) even does not show me file name like in [Debug Tutorial Part 5: Handle Leaks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6988/Debug-Tutorial-Part-5-Handle-Leaks). My executable has reference to 100 files.
I'd like to dig in direction with WinDbg, but for some reason it, installed from Windows 7 SDK, differs in functions from stated in docs, which prevents my further investigation?

I have:

WinDbg 6.12.0002.633 x86 (my process is 32 bit)

Windows 7 SP1 x64

Answer (score 2):

If you know the file being locked then the easiest thing to do would be to run ProcMon on your process and monitor the file and see which thread opened it up and then check on that thread in windbg. You can see which thread opened up a file in procmon by right clicking on the operation and going to properties. That will give you the thread ID and the thread stack trace.

If you can't do that I would try uninstalling windbg completely and then install the x64 version. The x64 can open both x86 and x64 and then try the commands again.